# Как записать параметры автоустановщика в Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, anaconda

CentOS при ручной установке создаёт файл /root/anaconda-ks.cfg, в котором записываются все параметры ручной установки. После этого файл можно использовать для типовой установки множества машин.

Как записать параметры автоустановщика для Ubuntu? Именно не создать новый файл самому, а записать параметры при установке новой системы.

Answer (score 4):

если при установке использовать текстовый режим, то запускаемая при этом программа *debian-installer* создаёт в целевой файловой системе каталог `/var/log/installer`, в котором содержится, в том числе, и файл `/var/log/installer/cdebconf/questions.dat`, который можно использовать в качестве «заготовки» для *preseed-файла*.

получить такую «заготовку» можно с помощью скрипта `debconf-get-selections` (из пакета *debconf-utils*):

```
$ sudo debconf-get-selections --installer > файл
$ sudo debconf-get-selections >> файл
```

из личного же опыта я бы посоветовал за основу для автоконфигурации брать «образцовый» файл [example-preseed.txt](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/example-preseed.txt), а содержимое полученного с помощью `debconf-get-selections` файла использовать разве что в качестве иллюстрации.

**дополнение** про разницу между *preseed-файлами* для [*debian*](https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/example-preseed.txt) и для [*ubuntu*](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/example-preseed.txt). помимо закомментированных строк есть всего четыре отличия:

1. добавлен параметр про отключение диалога выбора языка:

   ```
   d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
   ```
2. указан другой репозиторий с пакетами (что вполне естественно).
3. явно указано не шифровать домашний каталог первого создаваемого пользователя:

   ```
   d-i user-setup/encrypt-home boolean false
   ```
4. в качестве выбора задачи указана установка мета-пакета *ubuntu-desktop*:

   ```
   tasksel tasksel/first multiselect ubuntu-desktop
   ```

---

доп. информация:

- [Приложение B. Автоматическая установка с помощью списка ответов](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/apb.html.ru)
- [B.3. Создание файла ответов](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/apbs03.html.ru)
- [B.4. Содержимое файла ответов (для jessie)](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/apbs04.html.ru)
- [Automating Debian/Ubuntu Installs With Preseed](https://pthree.org/2008/05/20/automating-debianubuntu-installs-with-preseed/)

Comment: Дело в том, что имеющийся конфигурационный файл, ранее работавший на Ubuntu 14.04 без проблем, теперь не работает на Ubuntu 16.04. Вот и хотелось бы не только найти причину, но создать несколько вариантов загрузки с разными параметрами.

Comment: Не работает, значит останавливается на каком-либо пункте и ждёт ручного ввода.

Comment: Это не суть вопроса. Пункт уже включен в конфигурационный файл.

Comment: Нет. Могу ошибаться, но вроде на этом пункте localechooser/preferred-locale остановилось

Comment: alexander я вынужден акцентировать Ваше внимание на "Это не суть вопроса"!

Comment: @RemiZOffAlex, я честно пытался вам помочь, но если не хотите, то нет проблем. умываю руки.

Comment: @RemiZOffAlex Александр ответил на ваш изначальный вопрос. Если вам нужен был ответ на совсем другой вопрос, нужно было его и задавать.